# Baking Multiple Overlapping Textures With Transparency (Cycles)

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am running into an issue with baking. I have a large number of overlapping quads, each using a texture that has some transparency. However, when I try to bake them all onto an object, it only takes the outer-most quad, clipping all of the quads below it, instead of combining all overlapping quads based on their alphas. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Is it possible to bake like this? I have tried baking normals, emission, diffuse, and combined, but it seems no matter what I try the bake only prioritizes the outer-most quad.

Here's my mesh:

[image]

And here's what it bakes out to:

[image]

There should be a lot more overlap in the baked texture, but instead the transparent parts of the quad overlap.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think you can bake it. If your case is based on planes (faces) covering sphere (and they overlap or are on top of each other) baking wouldn't work.*

---

**Baking to the same object**
... takes a pixel at that location and bake it to a new image texture.

**Baking to another object**
... I assume you are using **Selected to Active** with **Cage** enabled, since original mesh are planes distorted on sphere and you are baking to another sphere. The baking ray is shot from cage surface in face normal direction and when hits a surface ray stops there and bake a value from that point. It means Alpha is not included in ray distance calculation only geometry.

Note: The pieces of colors in your second image of baked Normal map (that didnt blend in overall gradient) are probably texture seen through a gap between planes on the opposite side of sphere (a bake ray goes between meshes and hit a surface on opposite side).